# Can PHP determine the "genitive case" for a given string for a given locale?

Tags: php, string, locale

I'm trying to be able to display something like:

```
$1 health is very low right now.
```

Where $1 refers to a processed username/word/string. For example:

```
MagicalMage's health is very low right now.
```

Or:

```
Susy_Suss' health is very low right now.
```

Or (a difference case):

```
IBM's dominance is not as big as it once was.
```

The problem is that, not only does it have to handle the simple English rule of doing "'s" in the end except for strings that end with "s", as seen above, but also *any other language's special quirks*!

For example, in Swedish, it would be:

```
MagicalMages hälsa är väldigt låg just nu.
```

Or:

```
Susy_Suss hälsa är väldigt låg just nu.
```

Or (which happens to be identical to the English version):

```
Susy_Suss' hälsa är väldigt låg just nu.
```

Or (notice the colon instead of any apostrophe):

```
IBM:s dominans är inte så stor som den en gång var.
```

I'm sure there are *numerous* other versions for many other languages/locales as well. There always are such minor differences, because each place/language likes to be unique.

To make it clear, I'm not expecting PHP to **translate** the whole sentences for me. I simply want to be able to input the locale and the string (the username or company name, in this case) to be "genitivized" and have it spit out the correctly "processed" version for that language/region.

That is, if I input the string "IBM" and the locale is "en_US", it gives back:

```
IBM's
```

If I instead give it the locale "sv_SE", it gives back:

```
IBM:s
```

Clear as a day, no?

Answer (score 0):

To get to the point: No.

PHP can not do that. Furthermore there are some composer packages that handle different kinds of grammar (which are mostly for specific languages) and things like [pluralization in symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#message-format) - read up on [ICU message format](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages) if you want to know more about that.

However, there do not seem to be any packages available to do what you are asking, especially not so for multiple (or all) languages. Languages (that we speak, not programming languages) are often surprisingly more complex then you would think if you speak them fluently.

Since there is no such package, my best recommendation would be to jump on the chance and create a library by yourself and offer it for others (e.g. as composer package) and earn some community karma!